# Using JSON and XML as serialised objects in Python like in Java, rather than as dictionary maps

Tags: python, json, xml, jackson, jaxb

What do I need to do in Python, to serialise/deserialise objects to/from JSON and XML?

Does python have the ability that Java has, to serialise/deserialise or marshall/unmarshall objects to/from JSON and XML?

As far as my python knowledge goes, I could only get python to load a json into a dictionary map, which is not an acceptable form of "object".

Does python have capability correspondent to JAXB/Jackson for objects?

Comment: That would depend on the nature of your object.

Comment: Nature of an object would be like any object in an OOP language. https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp

Comment: I mean, how complex is your object? If it's just a container for data with a few simple methods, it's trivial to provide a custom JSON encoder for encoding (`__dict__` is useful) and hook for decoding.

Comment: They are DAOs and DTOs, for services which can get quite deep.